React WebRTC didn't receiving video from opponent
I'm trying to do P2P video chat. No error is displayed but at the same time, I didn't receive video from opponent.
Here is my client code.
  useEffect(() => {
    const onConnected = async () => {
      // Get media stream
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: true,
      })
      if (localVideoRef.current) {
        localVideoRef.current.srcObject = stream
      }

      const videoTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0]

      // Create a new PeerConnection for the local user
      localPeerConnection.current = new RTCPeerConnection(server)

      localPeerConnection.current.addTrack(videoTrack, stream)

      // Handle ICE candidates
      localPeerConnection.current.addEventListener("icecandidate", (event) => {
        if (event.candidate) {
          const { candidate } = event

          stompClient.send(
            `/app/local-candidate/${targetUserId}`,
            {},
            JSON.stringify(candidate)
          )
        }
      })

      stompClient.subscribe(
        `/user/${targetUserId}/topic/remote-candidate`,
        async (message: any) => {
          const candidate = JSON.parse(message.body)

          if (localPeerConnection.current?.remoteDescription) {
            await localPeerConnection.current?.addIceCandidate(
              new RTCIceCandidate(candidate)
            )
          }
        }
      )

      stompClient.subscribe(
        `/user/${myId}/topic/remote-description`,
        async (message: any) => {
          const description = JSON.parse(message.body)

          if (remotePeerConnection.current?.remoteDescription) {
            const answer = {
              type: "answer" as RTCSdpType,
              sdp: description.sdp,
            }

            await localPeerConnection.current?.setRemoteDescription(
              new RTCSessionDescription(answer)
            )
          }
        }
      )

      // Create an offer
      const offer = await localPeerConnection.current.createOffer()
      await localPeerConnection.current.setLocalDescription(offer)

      console.log("send offfer", offer)

      stompClient.send(
        `/app/local-description/${targetUserId}`,
        {},
        JSON.stringify(offer)
      )
    }

    if (stompClient && call) {
      onConnected()
    }
  }, [stompClient, targetUserId, call, localPeerConnection])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (stompClient) {
      // Handle receiving local description from the remote user
      stompClient.subscribe(
        `/user/${myId}/topic/local-description`,
        async (message: any) => {
          try {
            if (call) return

            setCall(true)

            const description = JSON.parse(message.body)

            const offer = {
              type: "offer" as RTCSdpType,
              sdp: description.sdp,
            }

            remotePeerConnection.current = new RTCPeerConnection(server)

            if (
              remotePeerConnection.current.signalingState !== "stable" ||
              !remotePeerConnection.current.remoteDescription
            ) {
              await remotePeerConnection.current?.setRemoteDescription(
                new RTCSessionDescription(offer)
              )

              remotePeerConnection.current.addEventListener(
                "icecandidate",
                (event) => {
                  if (event.candidate) {
                    const { candidate } = event

                    stompClient.send(
                      `/app/remote-candidate/${myId}`,
                      {},
                      JSON.stringify(candidate)
                    )
                  }
                }
              )

              remotePeerConnection.current.addEventListener(
                "track",
                (event) => {
                  console.log("Получен новый поток:", event.streams[0])
                  if (remoteVideoRef.current) {
                    remoteVideoRef.current.srcObject = event.streams[0]
                  }
                }
              )

              stompClient.subscribe(
                `/user/${myId}/topic/local-candidate`,
                async (message: any) => {
                  const candidate = JSON.parse(message.body)

                  if (remotePeerConnection.current) {
                    await remotePeerConnection.current.addIceCandidate(
                      new RTCIceCandidate(candidate)
                    )
                  }
                }
              )

              // Create an answer
              const answer = await remotePeerConnection.current.createAnswer()
              await remotePeerConnection.current.setLocalDescription(answer)

              console.log("receive answer", answer)

              stompClient.send(
                `/app/remote-description/${myId}`,
                {},
                JSON.stringify(answer)
              )
            }
          } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error setting remote description:", error)
          }
        }
      )
    }
  }, [
    stompClient,
    myId,
    targetUserId,
    call,
    remoteVideoRef,
    remotePeerConnection,
  ])

I am expecting to receive video from opponent. Also I didn't receive any error in console.  Can someone find the problem why I don't receive video from the opponent? It seems like it should work
